# iOS6 performance problems in iOS7 compatible app

Tags: memory, ios6, ios7, xcode5

My app worked beautifully on iOS6, but now I am deploying for it iOS6 and iOS7 through xCode 5 some users still running iOS6 have reported performance issues to me. I have not been able to recreate the issues on my one remaining iOS6 device, but it appears that some iOS6 users are experiencing memory problems which are causing the app's key process to terminate early.

I am debating whether to discontinue support for iOS6 for new releases and revert them to a stable pre-iOS7 version, using Apple's new feature for that. However, there is a cost involved as I am introducing some IAPs and monetization strategies to the new releases that ideally I would like available to all users.

Has anyone experienced similar performance issues or have any tips for handling this conundrum?

Answer (score 0):

I've made the decision to discontinue support for iOS6 in new releases, and to roll-back those users to an earlier version. I do not have confirmation, but my strong suspicion is that apps built for iOS7 do not run as efficiently on iOS6 in terms of memory usage etc, and it is important that users running iOS6 get an app that works effectively.

Comment: "..but my strong suspicion is that apps built for iOS7 do not run as efficiently on iOS6 in terms of memory usage etc,.." from Spinoxa. Agreed, we are running into the same concern. We are continuing support our iOS6 APP over iOS7 platform. The conversion of iOS6 into iOS7 that run on iOS7 platform performed poorly.

Comment: Good to know its not just me... although I'm talking about iOS7 apps performing poorly on iOS6. I'm making a last attempt to get it to work. Do you know if it is still possible to compile for iOS6 but not iOS7? I'll be gutted to not be able to support iOS6.